# Error autopy modulo de python

Tags: python

El error me aparece incluso en python:

> > > import autopy
> > >       Traceback (most recent call last):
> > >         File "", line 1, in 
> > >       ImportError: No module named autopy

version python 2.7.1

Comment: Esta pregunta (y otras que estás haciendo) denotan que no te has molestado en hacer una búsqueda por la red o te has leído un manual. Ese es el primer paso que deberías dar.

Answer (score 1):

Aquí tienes instaladores para tu versión de Python:

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/autopy/

Por otra parte, como parece que usas windows, hay otros como *pywinauto*, *pywin32*, *ctypes*,..., para hacer diferentes cosas en windows. Dependiendo de lo que vayas a hacer uno será más útil que otro.

Comment: se me olvido borrarlo lo publque cuando no sabia pero rapidamente encontre y no hace falta usar esa pagina aqui tienes todo lo que quieras http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/